# How can the value from a drop-down menu be accessed on form processing (PHP)?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am having a hard time populating this country dropdown. How can the selected value be accessed when the form is submitted and processed in the controller?

```
<div class="form-group form-group-default">
<label class="">Country</label>
<select class="full-width select2-offscreen" data-placeholder="Select Country" data-init-plugin="select2" tabindex="-1" title="">
<?php if(isset($country)&&!empty($country)) {?>
<?php foreach($country as $count_id): ?>
<option value="<?php $count_id -> id;?>" name="country"> 
<?php echo $count_id -> name;?> </option>
</optgroup>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php } ?>
</optgroup>
</select>
</div>
```

**Controller:**

```
$profile -> country_id = $request -> country;
```

Comment: Why do you have two closing option group tags (i.e. `</optgroup>`)? Unless you plan to make one an opening option group tag and move it before the start of the option tags, this is invalid HTML

Comment: @SamOnela ohh thank you sam!

Comment: No problem - feel free to refer to the [MDN optgroup page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/optgroup) for more info

Answer (score 2):

The name attribute should be on select element not on option element

Add name="country" attribute to select

```
<select name="country" class="full-width select2-offscreen" data-placeholder="Select Country" data-init-plugin="select2" tabindex="-1" title="">
```

And remove name attribute from option

```
<option value="<?php $count_id -> id;?>">
```

Comment: Thank you Sir! Have a great day!

Comment: @earl No problem. If this solved the issue, please mark as answer. Thanks